# How do I Reverse IP lookup for all hosted domains using same IP with linux centos 6-64 or cmd?

Tags: centos

using Linux centos 6-64 or Cmd, how do I do reverse IP lookup to find All the websites domains hosted on that IP. What we would like to know is not the hosting company website but the domains hosted using that same IP.

Example:

Suppose IP x.x.x.x is being hosted by Hosting Company Y.

But company Y is using same IP x.x.x.x to host 200 domains with same IP.

How do I check which are the 200 domains with same IP and print them to an output file?

Thank you

Comment: Peanut gallery, but this is likely not possible in many instances. Reverse DNS with e.g. `dig -x` relies on PTR records, which not all hosts have.

Comment: If the website supports HTTPS  (or another SSL/TLS protocol) try the SubjectAltName (SAN) extension of the certificate it offers -- for _some_ multitenant systems this includes some or all other hostnames this host at least intends to support -- although they may mismatch DNS if somebody makes a mistake. From commandline `openssl s_client | openssl x509 -text` is one way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably do this - although there are a fair number of websites which will give you partial lists (just Google the IP address)

The stumbling block you face is that the DNS lookups are a many:1 relationship, and reverse DNS does not provide a 1:many relationship lookup - and even if it did it would be inaccurate because it would need to be separately maintained list which would provide little benefit to the ISP and is a security risk.

As DNS does not help you, you would then look at the HTTP protocol.  Unfortunately this won't help either, as the web server will listen on the IP address and has no knowledge of what domain it is listening for - it is told the domain as part of the website negotiation - and can choose to handle that however it is configured, including answering for domains not in DNS.   There is no "external" way to exploit this information - although if you have a list of known domain names, you could see how it responds for each.

How the websites which provide some of this kind of information work is by finding domain names and resolving the DNS for them, and building up their own database.